# MySQL Workbench Visual Explain not working with MariaDB 10.3.9

Tags: mariadb, mysql-workbench, explain, mariadb-10.3

I recently installed MySQL Workbench 8.0.12 and MariaDB 10.3.9. I created my database and want to start fine tuning indexes and views. I can run a query with the EXPLAIN button and get the results in the tabular format (Tabular Explain). When I try to select "Visual Explain" from the dropdown menu, it switches back immediately to Tabular Explain. I tried almost everything and cannot switch to Visual Explain. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL Workbench is a MySQL product for MySQL servers only. There are no guarantees that it works with other servers and you you may encounter non-working areas (like you described) or may not even be able to connect to such a foreign server.